# Dataflow job is in running state but do not process any element from a pubsub subscription

Tags: apache-beam, publish-subscribe, python-3.8

I am trying to run a python Dataflow job which will read from pubsub subscription and write it to BQ.

The Dataflow job is getting triggered and is then goes in running state without fetching any data from a subscription. Any idea/clue, what could be going wrong? Same code is running fine on python 2.7

Python version is 3.8 &
apache-beam is 2.25.0.
Running code via Pycharm on macOS 11.2

Code (As job is not processing anything, I just kept print element in pardo function to see if it works)

```
import argparse
import logging

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam import DoFn
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions, StandardOptions

class DecodeMsgs(DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        print(element)
        return [element]

def run(subscription, pipeline_args=None):
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions()
    pipeline_options.view_as(StandardOptions).streaming = True
    p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)
    p | beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=subscription) | beam.ParDo(DecodeMsgs())
    result = p.run()
    result.wait_until_finish()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        '--subscription', required=True
    )

    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args()
    run(known_args.subscription, pipeline_args)
```

Arguments passed to a job

```
--subscription
<<projects/PROJECT/subscriptions/SUBSCRIPTION>>
--runner
DataflowRunner
--project
PROJECT
--temp_location
gs://temp_location
--staging_location
gs://staging_location
--subnetwork
<<regions/REGION/subnetworks/SUBNETWORK>>
--service_account_email
<<SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL>>
```

Here is python dependency list

```
apache-beam==2.25.0
apitools==0.1.4
avro-python3==1.9.2.1
bcrypt==3.2.0
bigquery==0.0.8
BigQuery-Python==1.15.0
cachetools==4.2.1
certifi==2020.12.5
cffi==1.14.4
chardet==4.0.0
crcmod==1.7
cryptography==3.3.1
dacktool==0.0.7
dbstream==0.0.30
dill==0.3.1.1
docopt==0.6.2
fastavro==1.3.0
fasteners==0.16
flatten-json==0.1.7
future==0.18.2
google-api-core==1.25.1
google-api-python-client==1.7.11
google-apitools==0.5.31
google-auth==1.24.0
google-auth-httplib2==0.0.3
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.2
google-cloud==0.34.0
google-cloud-bigquery==1.28.0
google-cloud-bigquery-storage==2.2.1
google-cloud-bigtable==1.6.1
google-cloud-build==2.0.0
google-cloud-core==1.5.0
google-cloud-datastore==1.15.3
google-cloud-dlp==1.0.0
google-cloud-language==1.3.0
google-cloud-pubsub==1.7.0
google-cloud-spanner==1.19.1
google-cloud-videointelligence==1.16.1
google-cloud-vision==1.0.0
google-crc32c==1.1.2
google-resumable-media==1.2.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.52.0
googleauthentication==0.0.14
grpc-google-iam-v1==0.12.3
grpcio==1.35.0
grpcio-gcp==0.2.2
hdfs==2.5.8
httplib2==0.17.4
idna==2.10
json-flatten==0.1
libcst==0.3.16
mock==2.0.0
mypy-extensions==0.4.3
numpy==1.19.5
oauth2client==4.1.3
oauthlib==3.1.0
pandas==1.2.1
paramiko==2.7.2
pbr==5.5.1
proto-plus==1.13.0
protobuf==3.14.0
pyarrow==0.17.1
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pycparser==2.20
pydot==1.4.1
pymongo==3.11.2
PyNaCl==1.4.0
pyparsing==2.4.7
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2020.5
PyYAML==5.4.1
requests==2.25.1
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
rsa==4.7
six==1.15.0
sshtunnel==0.1.5
typing-extensions==3.7.4.3
typing-inspect==0.6.0
uritemplate==3.0.1
urllib3==1.26.3
```

Comment: Is there any error from the worker log? There are also pubsub metrics on dataflow console, are there any request error metrics?

Comment: There is no error in worker log in fact it just says worker has started and nothing else..

Comment: Does the pipeline/supplied service account have the proper permissions to read from that subscription?

Comment: yes it has.. problem is no where in job/worker logs I see any error which makes it difficult to understand what is going wrong.

Comment: I suspect there is an issue in any of the python dependency as it worked couple of days back and then after installing some dependency it broke. I have updated original question with dependencies installed

Comment: Same piece of code is working with python3.6 and beam 2.26.0. So moving ahead with these versions.